# How to subscribe to messages created in a BizTalk orchestration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration that takes a message.  The target namespace is "http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" and the root element is "ORU_R01_23_GLO_DEF"

In the orchestration, I map the message to an intermediate message type in a construct shape.  The target namespace is "http://mycompany.com/myapplication" and the root element is "MyMessage".  The "MyMessage" message is then further mapped and then sent to a web service using a logical send port in the orchestration.  A WCF send port is then bound to the orchestration and everything works fine.  Everything works as expected.

Without altering the orchestration,  I want to create a send port that subscribes to the intermediate "MyMessage" message and writes it to a file.  To do this, I have created a send port with a filter of BTS.MessageType = http://mycompany.com/myapplication#MyMessage.

Even though messages are flowing through the orchestration,  my send port isn't picking up the message.  Is this the incorrect filter to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to subscribe to the 'MyMessage' message, or the same message that is sent to the logical Send Port bound to the physical WCF Send Port?

You have stated that:

> The "MyMessage" message is then further mapped and then sent to a web service using a logical send port in the orchestration. A WCF send port is then bound to the orchestration and everything works fine.

**Message not Published to MsgBox**

From what you have described, I would suggest that you do not have a Send Shape/Logical Send Port combination in your orchestration for the 'MyMessage' message, which is why you can't manually subscribe to this message type in a Send Port filter. The fact that you have not mentioned a 'Failed Routing Report' message further suggests that this is the case - this message type is generated when no subscriotion can be found for a message that is to be published to the MsgBox.

**Capture a Message's 'MessageType'**

If however you need to capture a copy of the message your are sending over the WCF Send Port, you will need to determine *its* MessageType and use *that* in your second Send Port subscription that writes the message out to file.

If you are unsure as to what MessageType to use, there is a simple trick to determine this information:

1. Stop (not Unenlist) the WCF Send Port
2. Send a message through your orchestration as normal - the message will be marked as 'Suspended Resumable' in the BizTalk Admin Console on the WCF Send Port.
3. Open the message in the BizTalk Admin Console and view its 'Message Context'; in the Message Context you will see its 'MessageType' property which you can then use to understand which subscription filter to use.
4. Start the WCF Send Port to flush the message.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change your orchestration, you could try archiving your message as it passes through the Send Pipeline in the (original) WCF Send Port - either write your own archiving component or use an [existing commercial component](http://www.atomic-scope.com/download-trial/). By using an archiving component in this manner, you will save yourself the expense of an extra subscription and the associated Send Port maintenance.

**Update:**

It sounds very much like the OP is not sending the intermediate message to the Message Box from their Orchestration (see comments). Message subscription will only work when a message is *published* to the Message Box - in this case, the message in question ('Message B') is an intermediate message that only lives within the context & lifetime of the orchestration. The OP needs to Send the message to a Direct Bound port within the Orchestration to allow the message to be subscribed to via a Send Port.

Comment: I'll boil the orchestration down.  Message A comes in.  It is mapped to a new message B, which is then mapped to a new message C.  Message C is sent to a WCF two way send port.  I can subscribe to message C and a also the response from the WCF send port.  What I can't seem to subscribe to is message B.  Message B is only an intermiedate message used by the orchestration to keep the maps more straightforward.  Ultimately, the integration only cares about message A and C, but from a diagnostic standport, I'd like to subscribe to message B when I need to.

Comment: Jeremy, it sounds like you're not sending Message B to the message box to allow the subscription on your Send Port to be activated. Message B will only live within the context of the orchestration and won't be published to the message box. You therefore need top send Message B to a logical send port that is configured as Direct Bound.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I thought that even if the message was merely constructed (not send out of a send port from the orchestration) it goes to the messagebox and can be subscribed to.  This is not the case though, it only goes to the message box if it goes through a logical send port in the orchesration.

Comment: Correct. I suppose an analogy would be a C# object that isn't serialized and written to disk will be lost when the app terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the pipelines of the Send Port. Should by XML, not Passthrougth.